# How to check if a firebase user is null in a fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am trying to retrieve lists of friend requests from my database in `RequestFragment` but when i run the code it crashes at getting current user id

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request, container, false);

    mRequestList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.request_list);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); //crash occurs here

    mRequestDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend_req").child(mCurrent_user_id);
    mRequestDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);


    mRequestList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRequestList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return mMainView;
}
```

if i remove the `RequestFragment` and run the app it starts up correctly but immediately i log out app starts to crash again.

i later found out that when a user is not logged in current user id is null causing it to crash.so i tried using this code

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        sendToStart();

    }else {

    }
```

to check if user is null but it dosen't work.

Comment: If `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` returns `null` unexpectedly, always attach an auth state listener to see if that helps. See the first code sample here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: i tried it but it still crashes

Comment: That means that no user is signed in to Firebase Authentication. That is what your `onStart` detects, so what do yo mean when you say that "it doesn't work" there?